# ColdFusion isDefined getting Not Defined error

Tags: coldfusion

I have:

```
<cfif not isDefined(activity)>
    <cfset activity="">
</cfif>
```

And I'm getting the error: :"Variable ACTIVITY is undefined."

Huh?

Oh, and the error is with `isDefined`, not with the `cfset`.

Comment: For the record, you can use IsDefined("struct.variable") and it's just as reliable as StructKeyExists() so long as noone does something silly and tries to create a struct named after a cf scope in the variables scope. While variables isn't a reserved word, it's silly to create an object name that you know a system gives special meaning to. Variables.['reserved'_scope] = structnew() is the only fault I've ever seen anyone claim evidence of in the isDefined vs StructKeyExists debate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[isDefined takes the name of a variable](https://cfdocs.org/isdefined), not the variable itself:

```
<cfif not isDefined("activity")>
    <cfset activity="">
</cfif>
```

Comment: `iaDefined()` is a bit of an outdated and unreliable way checking for a variable's existence: it's not really been the correct approach since CF5. It's risky because - using your example above - it'll return true if any of `variables.activity`, `form.activity`, `URL.activity` (perhaps some others) exists. And it will check a whole bunch of scopes, trying to return `true`. I have also in the past had it return false positives on the session scope (this was back in the days of CFMX7 though: might not be an issue now). One should only use `structKeyExists()` for this sort of requirement.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
<cfif structKeyExists(VARIABLES, 'Activity')>
<cfset Activity = "Something" />
</cfif>
```

Comment: Loose the `len()` / `trim()` and I'd vote this as the better of the two answers. You're checking existence, not whether or not it's a string with non-whitespace length. `structKeyExists()` is, however, a better solution than `isDefined()`.

Comment: The quick and dirty solution fixed the problem first, but I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: @volume one (won't tag), what is `VARIABLES` in the above solution? Something to add to the question is that `activity` is a parameter from a form, as in `FORM.activity`. So, would it be `structKeyExists(FORM, 'activity')`?

Comment: @abalter yes that would be correct. Sometimes a variable can exist, but it may be empty hence I always check that it contains a value. So I would do `<cfif structKeyExists(FORM, 'Activity') AND Len(Trim(FORM.Activity)>` which is what I originally posted. Equally if you want to check whether it doesn't exist then just do this instead `<cfif NOT structKeyExists(FORM, 'Activity') AND Len(Trim(FORM.Activity) EQ 0>`

Comment: @volumeone, thanks. So, in referencing @Adam's comment, what is the purpose of the `Len(Trim(...))`?

Comment: `Len(Trim(#VariableName#))` is checking if the variable has any content (checks the length) other than whitespace (trim gets rid of whitespace).